# solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, solr, apache-tika

I am working on an internal project in my company that requires solr, but I could not manage to link it to Tika. I bought the apache solr 4 cookbook yet I couldn't figure out the solution.

1. I copied the required jar files into a lib directory
2. I added the lib directory in solrconfig.xml

when I remove `start="lazy"` in `requesthandler="update/extract"` I get the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler'
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
```

Comment: can you post your configuration ?

Comment: I believe the path is relative to your `SolrCore` directory rather than `solr.solr.home` directory. Hope that helps for folks that would like to keep paths relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work after replacing ../../dist and ../../contrib with their absolute paths. 
It is very wierd as I am sure I placed these files where they should be.

Thank you very much Jayendra for your replies.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have the apache-solr-cell jar and its dependencies in the extraction lib in the Solr library and its being loaded by Solr when Solr starts.

```
<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../contrib/extraction/lib" />
```

Comment: I made sure to add the these files.

Comment: does the cell file show up when the solr loads its core and id the file present at the location ?

Comment: no, it does not.
I tried to modify the permissions of the file containing solr and thought it would work, yet it still doesn't.

Comment: cocnerning my configuration.
I added this line to the solrconfig.xml:
<lib dir="../../extract" regex=".*\.jar" />
I placed all the /contrib jars and the cell jar file in this folder.
I also made sure to not change the file structure of solr.
regards,
Omar

Comment: And note that in 4.10.4 (at least in my case), the `regex` for the first line needed to be changed from `apache-solr-cell-...` to `solr-cell-...`

Comment: Also try adding ...  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar"/>

Answer (score 0):

I tried absolute paths, and all the other suggestions here. What worked for me is copying the solr-cell-*.jar into a new folder called "libs" in my "Collection1" folder. Then editing the solrconfig.xml to point to that copied solr-cell-*.jar.